# Button Border Not Showing

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-button

I try to put a border for a button in android but unfortunately I can't see the button border.

Drawable File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="12dp" />
            <stroke android:width="3px" android:color="#7E8082" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

XML

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="122dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_signup"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_semibold"
        android:text="Create an Account"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_login" />
```

[image: I want this button]

Comment: Have you tried using `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton` as the Button?

Comment: Are you using a `MaterialComponents` theme? If so the `android:background` attribute would be ignored. You should use the built-in `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton`.

Comment: @HenryTwist It is not totally correct. Starting with 1.2.0 you can use the android:background attribute in a MaterialButton.

Comment: You're right @GabrieleMariotti, I stand corrected. That one must have slipped past me in the changelogs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use a custom drawable, just use a `MaterialButton`:

```
       <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
           app:strokeColor="#7E8082"
           app:strokeWidth="1dp"
           app:cornerRadius="12dp"/>
```

[image]

Comment: Working  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a selector for single option use `shape` directly

**bg_signup**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#cdcdcd"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="4dp"
    />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#000"
    />
</shape>
```

Comment: Although it is unnecessary, using a selector shouldn't cause any problems here? So I'm not sure that this actually *solves* the problem.

Answer (score -1):

use Style  attribute instead of  `android:background="@drawable/bg_signup"`

make a custom style then call it `android:style="@style/bg_signup"`